# How to add .pdf document in Qweb report in Odoo 10?

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I am working in qweb report for `hr.expense.sheet`.

Here we have multiple expenses lines where we can add documents with "Documents" button.

Here we find `.pdf` document from `ir.attachment` but How to display in Qweb report?

Comment: Mm I don´t understand your question. Could you explain it better?

Comment: Suppose, there is a document stored in ir.attachment table.
Here document 's extension is PDF.
Now I want to display this pdf into Qweb report.

Comment: The Qweb Reports are printed in PDF. Do you mean that you want to see which Qweb Report created some specific PDF?

Comment: Do you want to see your custom uploaded pdf in relavent Qweb report ?

Comment: Do you want to see your custom uploaded pdf in relavent Qweb report ?
--> Yes  exactly